# Do ATAGS get overwritten by the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, nexus-4

I have read that the ATAGS (used on arm processors to provide the Linux kernel with information such as the memory layout) are loaded to [SystemRAM base]+0x100. On the Nexus 4  the SystemRAM base is at 0x8020000. I also know that the kernel is loaded to 0x80208000. I have verified that is is the case by dumping the portion of memory using the command:

`dd if=/dev/mem bs=1 skip=$((0x80208000)) count=$((0x200)) of=kimage_hdr`

The header output file matches the expected header of an uncompressed kernel image. However when I try to view the atags with the following command, the resulting file does not contain the a valid ATAG list.

`dd if=/dev/mem bs=1 skip=$((0x80200100)) count=$((0x200)) of=atags`

I am running Android and have used the kexec_load syscall to reload and reboot the kernel explicitly placing the ATAG information at 0x80201000 (0x80200100 does not align to a page boundary). The kernel reloads, but even when I look explicitly at this section the ATAGS are gone.

Does anybody know if the kernel reallocates, or otherwise modifies, this area of memory, or am I doing something wrong?

BTW: I know I can get the ATAGS through /proc/atags but I want know where they are now stored in physical ram.

Comment: I thought the address to the tags was passed into the kernel via a register from the bootloader, wherever the bootloader left them.  Not sure though

Comment: Your right. The address of the atags (commonly 0x100 above system ram base) is loaded into the CPU reg before the boot loader jumps to the kernel entry point. However, the boot loader must also load the stags array into ram, or else passing the address would be pointless. I want know why I can't read those atags from physical memory after the kernel has booted.

Comment: After the tags are copied to their destination variables, the physical memory goes into the general **free pool** and is used for what ever purpose it is needed for.  Why would you leave it?