# On 32 bit ARM Linux, for address range (0xC000 0000 - 0xC000 3FFF), what is it used for?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, kernel

I know that

- 0xC000 4000 - 0xC000 7FFF(16KB) is for swapper PGD
- 0xC000 8000 -    some_address is used for kernel data and text.

Question is: for address range  (0xC000 0000 - 0xC000 3FFF), what it is used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [ARM memory.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arm/memory.txt) and [Linux managing less than 1GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528568/how-does-the-linux-kernel-manage-less-than-1gb-physical-memory) .  The situation is typical, but not set in stone.

The `PAGE_OFFSET` (0xc0000000) is the start of RAM and the 'ATAGS' are [usually placed here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S#n278).  After the **atags** are copied, the [memory is freed for general use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865430/do-atags-get-overwritten-by-the-kernel); Ie `kmalloc()` or other allocations.